# Unable to Mount Seagate Array from Iomega

Tags: mount, automount

I am new to Ubuntu so please be kind!

My (Windows based) Iomega Storcentre ix2-200 stopped working, with all my business data upon it.

Iomega helpfully told me that I should get Fedora, remove the Seagate hard drives and recover the information by connecting via a USB / SATA cable. First I could not get Fedora to load (due to it needing an Internet connection before loading complete) so I got Ubuntu - much easier to load.

Yesterday I had one icon on computer showing marked "Array", this morning I have two icons one entitled "1", and the other "RAID-1 Array", both have an icon on top that is a pale blue circle with a "1" in the middle. I have downloaded mdadm.

I have used fdisk -l and had the following response from Linux:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x246b3fe6

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT
```

I have tried the "mount" command but either am using the wrong file type (I can't seem to find anywhere what system is used) or simply don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

to access terminal, click on dash and type in terminal in the search bar that opens. To mount the Array try the following command once you find and open terminal.

```
sudo mount -t Array /dev/sdf2 /media/"Portable HD"
```

if it mounts than you should be good to go. If it doesn't mount your Array may be too far gone to recover without the use of a data recovery service.

Comment: Thank you - I bought a Linux book pre dating this release and they pointed "Terminal" somewhere totally different - I found it in the end. I have made progress, using sudo fdisk -l I have found the drive and its name (/dev/sdb1) - what I don't have is the file system or the command for whatever system it is - the error message suggests "use gnu parted" but can't find command for that. Thanks for this help though.

Comment: gparted is partition formatting program, be careful with it as you might accidently wipe your entire hdd and lose all your files you are trying to save.